# Gantt editable chart for ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gantt-chart

I'm looking for an editable Gantt chart component that can be used in ReactJS. The need is to plot a resource Gantt chart where the user can change tasks on the time axis and also between the resources.

Preferably open source.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is really good too 
https://github.com/guiqui/react-timeline-gantt
Can load thousands of records, has infinite scroll and task dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gantt chart here which is ReactJS and open source (MIT) but as far as I can see not editable. But if you know ReactJS, making it editable would not be a huge job.

Docs: https://github.com/jamrizzi/react-gantt

Demo: https://jamrizzi.github.io/react-gantt/

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this React Gantt chart component made with the help of dhtmlxGantt (js gantt chart library): https://github.com/DHTMLX/react-gantt-demo

Tutorial: https://dhtmlx.com/blog/create-react-gantt-chart-component-dhtmlxgantt/